# Crawling list of bugs with scrapy does not go to page 3,4,5

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am trying to scrape list of chrome bugs that is already fixed. It works for 1st and 2nd page, however, for some reason it stops at 3rd page. I set DEPTH_LIMIT = 1 in setting.py. Is this related to chrome policy in which probably they limit the amount of data that can be scraped? Thanks in advance!

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "craig"
    start_urls = ["http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=1&q=status%3Afixed&sort=&groupby=&colspec=ID+Pri+M+Iteration+ReleaseBlock+Cr+Status+Owner+Summary+OS+Modified+Type+Priority+Milestone+Attachments+Stars+Opened+Closed+BlockedOn+Blocking+Blocked+MergedInto+Reporter+Cc+Project+Os+Mstone+Releaseblock+Build+Size+Restrict+Security_severity+Security_impact+Area+Stability+Not+Crash+Internals+Movedfrom+Okr+Review+Taskforce+Valgrind+Channel+3rd"]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[starts-with(., "Next")]/@href'))),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("status%3Afixed",), deny=("detail?",)), callback="parse_items", follow=True)

    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        table = hxs.select("//table[@id='resultstable']")

    items = []

        count = 1
        for count in range(1,100):
            row = table.select("tr[" + str(count) + "][@class='ifOpened cursor_off']")  
        item = CraiglistSampleItem()

        item["summary"] = row.select("td[@class='vt col_8'][2]/a/text()").extract()     
        item["summary"] = str(item["summary"][0].encode("ascii","ignore")).strip()

        item["id"] = row.select("td[@class='vt id col_0']/a/text()").extract()      
        item["id"] = str(item["id"][0].encode("ascii","ignore")).strip()

        print item["summary"]
            count = count + 1
            items.append(item)

        return(items)
```

Comment: even DEPTH_LIMIT = 10 it still gives me the same data

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's what `DEPTH_LIMIT = 1` does. The third page is depth 2, so it won't be crawled. Set `DEPTH_LIMIT = 0` and your crawler will work.

Comment: it's still the same. It just gives me 297 data.

Comment: @user2537643: Your first rule should have a `follow=True`, not the first.

Comment: I removed the second rule and changed the first rule to:

rules = (
     Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("status%3Afixed",), deny=("detail?",), restrict_xpaths=('//a[starts-with(., "Next")]',))
      , callback="parse_items", follow=True),
     
    )

But it did not scrape anything. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @user2537643: You don't need to remove the second rule. The first one clicks the Next button. The second one (without `follow=True`) will scrape each individual issue.

Comment: @user2537643: Also, you do know that you can get the issues as a CSV file, right? Scroll to the bottom of the page and on the bottom right there will be a **CSV** link.

Comment: I changed it to :
rules = (
     Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[starts-with(., "Next")]/@href')), follow=True),
     Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("status%3Afixed",), deny=("detail?",)), callback="parse_items", follow=True)
    
    ). But still did not work, and stop at the 3rd page. Yes, I do know there is a link to download CSV. But 100 data for each page which means I need to click 50 times to get 5000 data.